# Google Analytics - Data reporting

Tags: google-analytics

My website has lot of search features .

Ex: I can search for all the first names of the people in the organization and fetch their grades.

In Google analytics, how  can  I track what is the most searched name ? Please help!

Comment: Doesn't Google documents its functionalities?

Comment: I could not find any document which could do the above.

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en, but frankly I think this should rather go to webmasters.stackexchange.org since it's a reporting question rather than a programming problem.

Comment: Thank you. I used the SiteSearch feature